# Copy files to new dir and append date

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm copying over some files (txt/log files) from C:\Application\Logs\Log.txt (and Log2.txt etc) to C:\Logs

Code:

```
If Not File.Exists("C:\Logs\Log.txt") Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
        "C:\Application\Logs\Log.txt",
        "C:\Logs\Log.txt")
            End If
```

If the button is pressed multiple times, this will fail as the logs already exist in C:\Logs. So, I would like to append date to the end of the log before it is placed in the folder. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just add the date after its moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirement, I think it will be better to prevent the multiple clicks to make duplicate process than to append the date:

```
Dim isProcessed As Boolean = False
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If isProcessed Then
        Return
    End If
    isProcessed = True

    If Not File.Exists("C:\Logs\Log.txt") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(
          "C:\Application\Logs\Log.txt",
          "C:\Logs\Log.txt")
    End If

    isProcessed = False
End Sub
```

Nevertheless, if you want to add the `DateTime`, you could do that by having `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff")` appended as text in your log file name too:

```
Dim isProcessed As Boolean = False
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If isProcessed Then
        Return
    End If
    isProcessed = True

    Dim filename As String = "C:\Logs\Log_" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_fff") & ".txt"
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\Application\Logs\Log.txt", filename)

    isProcessed = False
End Sub
```

The check `If Exist` is no longer needed, since the time is different now

Comment: thank you! any suggestions on to easily add the code in this code to append the text to the filenames?

Comment: Ah yes, note how I make the `filename` variable using `DateTime.Now`, basically, you append the date time info to the file name

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much - I made a small tweak since I have 2 log files, so I added another "filename2".